# What are the benefits of using a UINavigationController over adding a view with addSubView?

Tags: ios, performance, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

Let's say I have two pages with two `UIViewControllers`, **`UIViewController1`** & **`UIViewController2`**.

If I want to show a `UIViewController2` on top of `UIViewController1` I have three options:

1. using `UINavigationController` `pushViewController`.
2. using `presentViewController`.
3. `addSubView` : `UIViewController1.view.addSubView(UIViewController2.view)`

If I need to a transition between my views, I prefer the third option because it gives me much more control over the views.

Is there any difference between these three options in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

Before iOS 6 you were not supposed to do option 3. View controllers were meant to control the entire screen. In iOS 6 Apple added support for parent and child view controllers. You could make another view controller your child and add it's content views to yours.

If you are going to use option 3 then that's what you need to do. If you don't you will have a variety of problems.

There is even support for parent/child view controller built into storyboards. You can add a container view to a view controller, and then control drag from the container view onto another view controller's scene. When you do that the system creates an "embed segue" that sets up the child view controller inside the container view and wires up the parent/child relationship for you.

Your first 2 options are for when you want the new view controller to replace, or at least cover, the first view controller. Option 3 is for when you want a region of your screen to be managed by another view controller.

Option 3 (using a child view controller) does mean that both view controllers will be active and in memory at the same time, so you can't release the covered view controller's data storage while it's inactive like you can in a push or modal presentation. However unless your view controllers hold and present huge data structures this isn't much of a concern. In both a push and a modal presentation the covered view controller sticks around in memory anyway, waiting to be uncovered. You have to take special steps in order to free any memory while a view controller's view is covered and then reallocate it when it is displayed again - something that is unusual.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so with the first tow options i could release the the previous controllers, but with the first one i can't ! .     could you please give me a link for a tutorial which describe How to free a memory using UINavigationController and then recreate the viewController again when the user press the back button.

Comment: No, you can't release the previous view controller in any of the schemes you're talking about. In a modal presentation, the new view controller displays on top of the previous one. With a navigation controller, pushing a new view controller adds the new one to a navigation stack, and all previous view controllers stick around.

Comment: I'm talking about Model data that represents the contents you are showing in the VC. You can code your view controllers such that they release their model object(s) when they are not on-screen, and reload it when they come back, but most people don't do that. (BTW, the word for the number 2 is "two", not "tow".)

Comment: thank you very much, but also i can release the model with the third option, if i track the view hierarchy. it just a little bit of work. right ?

Comment: Probably not, no. If the child view controller is still on-screen and active, how would you release it's model data?

Comment: I think you're worrying about things you should not be worrying about though. Unless your view controllers are holding multiple MEGABYTES of data, the model data for 2 view controllers is not going to introduce meaningful memory pressure on your app. It just won't.

Answer (score 0):

Just for two view controllers, it will not create major difference. UINavigationController is mainly used to maintain navigation stack.

But as you are having just two view controllers, you can use alternate way also.

If you are looking for transitions with NavigationController, you can use UIView Transitions for customisation of push pop animation.

Please refer following links for UIView Transitions

https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions--more

http://applidium.github.io/ADTransitionController/

Comment: thank you for your answer, and if i have 4 view controller does that effect the performance, or any thing else ?

Comment: I dont think it will create any issue with performance. But you just need to maintain view hierarchy.

Comment: Welcome and No problem, you can wait. Feel free if you require any other assistance